# How to wrap an async function in a loop or How to run an async function in a loop?

Tags: javascript

This is my function:

```
async function mintNFT(tokenURI) {
  const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(PUBLIC_KEY, "latest"); //get latest nonce
  //the transaction
  const tx = {
    from: PUBLIC_KEY,
    to: contractAddress,
    nonce: nonce,
    gas: 500000,
    data: nftContract.methods.mintNFT(PUBLIC_KEY, tokenURI).encodeABI(),
  };
  const signPromise = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY);
  signPromise
    .then((signedTx) => {
      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
        signedTx.rawTransaction,
        function (err, hash) {
          console.log(
            "The hash of your transaction is: ",
            hash,
            "\nCheck Alchemy's Mempool to view the status of your transaction!"
          );
          if (!err) {
          } else {
            console.log(
              "Something went wrong when submitting your transaction:",
              err
            );
          }
        }
      );
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Promise failed:", err);
    });
}
```

I have tried run it in a loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  mintNFT("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/cid/" + i);
}
```

But it has error every iteration:

```
Something went wrong when submitting your transaction: Error: Returned error: replacement transaction underpriced
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/user/Projects/contract/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at /home/user/Projects/contract/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:302:36
    at /home/user/Projects/contract/node_modules/@alch/alchemy-web3/dist/cjs/util/promises.js:28:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  data: null
}
```

But if i run function one time outside a loop, it has no errors.

How to run that function in a loop or how to wrap function code with loop?

Comment: I think you should try to verify that exactly what's running in the loop is the same thing in your code with no loop.

Comment: The error reads `Returned error: replacement transaction underpriced`. How is that related to the loop?

Comment: @peter-krebs it is related because i haven't this error when i run function outside the loop

Comment: @tkol what do you mean. I can't understand you

Comment: @satad227 you said `if i run function one time outside a loop, it has no errors.` I'm saying you should verify that that's accurate, that the request that's working outside of the loop is identical to the one running inside the loop. If they aren't identical, then it's not the "loop" that's the problem.

Comment: @tkol i found. Row nonce(transactions count) in tx every time should change. If i run it one time, it will be 11. If i run it again, it will be 12. But when i run it in the loop. At first iteration `nonce` = 12 but at second it gives error but should give 13.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to make an async loop that waits for the previous one to finish before starting the next request.

Comment: @tkol maybe yes. `nonce` is last transaction number. Code has error when nonce is invalid number(like 10, 10 is invalid because i already have transaction number 10). I tried run `const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(PUBLIC_KEY, "latest");` outside the function then add one to nonce in the end of function. But nonce can not get in time valid value and i have similar error, because: `Promise { <pending> }`. The error is that the variable cannot update or get a number in time(`nonce`)